# why non-pic code can't be totally ASLR using run-time fixups?

Tags: linux, x86-64, elf, aslr, position-independent-code

I understand that PIC code makes ASLR randomization more efficient and easier since the code can be placed anywhere in memory with no change in code. But if i understand right according to Wikipedia [relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)) dynamic linker can make "fixups" at runtime so a symbol can be located although code being not position-independent. But according to many answers i saw here non-pic code can't `ASLR` sections except the stack(so cant randomize program entry point). If that is correct then what are runtime fixups are used for and why can't we just fixup all locations in code at runtime before program start to make program entry point randomized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL:DR: Not all uses of absolute address will have relocation info in a non-PIE executable (ELF type EXEC, not DYN).**  Therefore the kernel's program-loader can't find them all to apply fixups.

Thus there's no way to retroactively enable ASLR for executables built as non-PIE.  There's no way for a traditional executable to flag itself as having relocation metadata for every use of an absolute address, and no point in adding such a feature either since if you want text ASLR you'd just build a PIE.

Because ELF-type EXEC Linux executables are guaranteed to be loaded / mapped at the fixed base address chosen by the linker at link time, it would be a waste of space in the executable to make symbol-table entries for internal symbols.  So toolchains didn't do that, and there's no reason to start.  That's simply how traditional ELF executables were designed; Linux switched from a.out to ELF back in the mid 90s before stack ASLR was a thing, so it wasn't on people's radar.

e.g. the absolute address of `static char buf[100]` is probably embedded somewhere in the machine code that uses it (if we're talking about 32-bit code, or 64-bit code that puts the address in a register), but there's no way to know where or how many times.

Also, for x86-64 specifically, the default code model for non-PIE executables guarantees that static addresses (text / data / bss) will all be in the low 2GiB of virtual address space, so 32-bit absolute signed or unsigned addresses can work, and `rel32` displacements can reach anything from anything.  That's why non-PIE compiler output uses `mov $symbol, %edi` (5 bytes) to put an address in a register, instead of `lea symbol(%rip), %rdi` (7 bytes).  https://godbolt.org/z/89PeK1

So even if you did know where every absolute address was, you could only ASLR it in the low 2GiB, limiting the number of bits of entropy you could introduce.  (I think Windows has a mode for this: LargeAddressAware = no.  But Linux doesn't.  [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux)  Again, PIE is a better way to allow text ASLR, so people (distros) should just compile for that if they want its benefits.)

**Unlike Windows, Linux doesn't spend huge effort on things that can be handled better and more efficiently by recompiling binaries from source.**

That being said, GNU/Linux *does* support fixup relocations for *64-bit* absolute addresses even in PIC / PIE ELF shared objects.  That's why beginner code like NASM `mov rdi, BUFFER` can work even in a shared library: use `objdump -drwC -Mintel` to see the relocation info on that use of the symbol in a `mov reg, imm64` instruction.  An `lea rdi, [rel BUFFER]` wouldn't need any relocation entry if `BUFFER` wasn't a global symbol.  (Equivalent of C `static`.)

---

You might be wondering why metadata is essential:

**There's no reliable way to search text/data for possible absolute addresses; false positives would be possible**.  e.g. `/usr/bin/ld` probably contains `0x401000` as the default start address for an x86-64 executable.  You don't want ASLR of `ld`'s code+data to also change its defaults.  Or that integer value could have come up in any number of ways in many programs, e.g. as a bitmap.  And of course x86-64 machine code is variable length so there's no reliable way to even distinguish opcodes from immediate operands in the most general case.

And also potentially false negatives.  Not super likely that an x86 program would construct an absolute address in a register with multiple instructions, but it's certainly possible.  However in non-x86 code, that would be common.

RISC machines with fixed-length instructions can't put a 32-bit address into a 32-bit instruction; there'd be no room left for anything else.  So to load from static storage, the absolute addresses would have to be split across multiple instructions, like MIPS `lui $t0, %hi(0x612300)` / `lw $t1, %lo(0x612300)($t0)` to load from a static variable at absolute address 0x612300.  (There would normally be a symbol name in the asm source, but it wouldn't appear in the final linked binary unless it was `.globl`, so I used numbers as a reminder.)  Instructions like that don't have to come in pairs; the same high-half of the address could be reused by other accesses into the same array or struct in later instructions.

Comment: I get the impression that people saw relocation as a necessary evil on 16-bit systems without virtual memory, where all programs shared the same address space, and gratefully abandoned support for it with the move to 32-bit systems, where programs could always be loaded at a constant virtual address.  As  you say, the usefulness of ASLR was not foreseen.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yeah, that's a good way of looking at it for the main executable.  Shared libraries do still need either relocation or position-independent code, because only the main executable can be guaranteed of claiming its own spot in virtual address space.  (IIRC, Linux a.out libraries *did* need to be manually relocated, and you could like optimize your shared libs or something by ahead-of-time relocating them to non-conflicting base addresses.  Or maybe I'm thinking of DLLs?  I started using Linux soon after ELF replaced a.out, so I read about the changeover but never experienced it).

Comment: @NateEldredge: Also note that Linux ELF shared objects *do* support runtime fixups, often used for a jump table of absolute addresses as data.  But yeah, 32-bit PIC has significant overhead because of the lack of EIP-relative addressing, so fixups would have been significantly more performant for shared libraries.  *But* then they couldn't share text between processes, and taken longer to load.  Unix systems often start lots of short-lived processes.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first have a look at Windows before having a look at Linux:

Windows' `.EXE` files (programs) typically have a so-called "base relocation table" and they have an "image base".

The "image base" is the "desired" start address of the program; if Windows loads the program to that address, no relocation needs to be done.

The "base relocation table" contains a list of all values in a program which represent addresses. If the program is loaded to a different address than the "image base", Windows must add the difference to all values listed in that table.

If the `.EXE` file does not contain a "base relocation table" (as far as I know some 32-bit GCC versions generate such files), it is not possible to load the file to another address.

This is because the following C code statements will result in exactly the same machine code (binary code) if the variable `someVariable` is located at the address 12340000, and it is not possible to distinguish between them:

```
long myVariable = 12340000;
```

And:

```
int * myVariable = &someVariable;
```

In the first case, the value 12340000 must not be changed in any situation; in the second case, the address (which is 12340000) must be changed to the real address if the program is loaded to another address.

If the "base relocation table" is missing, there is no information if the value 12340000 is an integer value (which must not be changed) or an address (which must be changed).

So the program must be loaded to some fixed address.

I'm not sure about the latest 32-bit Linux releases, but at least in older 32-bit Linux versions there was nothing like a "base relocation table" and programs did not use PIC. This means that these programs had to be loaded to their "favorite" address.

I don't know about 64-bit Linux programs, but if a program is compiled the same way as the (older) 32-bit programs, they also must be loaded to a certain address and ASLR is not possible.